# Cordova/AngularJS UI-Router Wrapping External Site Without iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, iframe

I am pretty sure I know the answer, but throwing this out in hopes that someone has an idea I have not thought of.

I am doing a Cordova app for a client that wants one of the pages to have their current mobile site wrapped (below navigation bar). The app is using Angular JS and I was just going to wrap that page with an iFrame... but ran into the X-Frame-Options: Deny issue that they wrapped their entire site under.

Ideally they will remove that, but with politics it might not be possible.

Is there any way else that I can load this site up without an iframe? I am guessing not because of the security issues this was trying to solve in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I was able to solve it in the end was to use a plug-in that launched a new webview with the site inside it, then modifying the webview and plugin to look like the rest of the app.

Here is the great plugin I started with:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser